# Output variables within a by group only if

Tags: sas

My first time posting. I'm pretty new to SAS programming (actually all programming).  This seems like a simple problem but can't figure it out.  I have some crosstab output and I'm trying to get it into shape for easy output to tables.  I want to retain the first observation in a by group if  there are only 3 observations in that group.  If there are more than 3 observations, I want to retain all observations but the last.  So, for example, here's what I have:

```
Group1  Group2  Percent
var1    1   0.25
var1    1   0.75
var1    1   1
var1    2   0.4
var1    2   0.6
var1    2   1
var1    3   0.7
var1    3   0.3
var1    3   0.6
var2    1   0.1
var2    1   0.2
var2    1   0.4
var2    1   0.3
var2    1   1
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   1
var2    3   0.7
var2    3   0.1
var2    3   0.05
var2    3   0.05
var2    3   0.1
```

and here's what I want in a new dataset

```
Group1  Group2  Percent
var1    1   0.25
var1    2   0.4
var1    3   0.7
var2    1   0.1
var2    1   0.2
var2    1   0.4
var2    1   0.3
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    2   0.2
var2    3   0.7
var2    3   0.1
var2    3   0.05
var2    3   0.05
```

Hopefully, that's clear but please let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Hi Kate, welcome to SO and SAS.  To make this a good question, you should include some code showing what you've done to attempt to solve this problem.  While we don't necessarily mind code-less questions that ask about certain techniques, a question is more answerable when it includes code both to show the skill level appropriate to answer to and to show that you've made some effort and aren't just asking us to do work for you.

Comment: In particular - are you familiar with `first.` and `last.` concepts in by group processing?  If not, you might look up that first and it will help your attempt I suspect.

Comment: How did you derive those datasets? Did you use a SAS proc or are those what you're starting with? If its from a PROC there may be a way to incorporate it directly and skip this step.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Joe. In the future I'll include code as well. Yes, I am generally familiar with first., last.    I was able to use these to generate a count variable by group but then got stuck. Next time I'll provide more information...

Comment: Thanks for your question, Reeza.  It looks like Foxer was able to work out my problem.  I'll strive for a bit more clarity in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I've broken it out in a few steps to help you see the logic and have used both data steps and SQL. Basically you want to count how many are in each group and keep all counts (the count within the group and the total count) around so you can use them to make your final logic.

```
data test;
    length GROUP1 $5 GROUP2 PERCENT 8;
    input GROUP1 $ GROUP2 PERCENT;
    datalines;
    var1    1   0.25
    var1    1   0.75
    var1    1   1
    var1    2   0.4
    var1    2   0.6
    var1    2   1
    var1    3   0.7
    var1    3   0.3
    var1    3   0.6
    var2    1   0.1
    var2    1   0.2
    var2    1   0.4
    var2    1   0.3
    var2    1   1
    var2    2   0.2
    var2    2   0.2
    var2    2   0.2
    var2    2   0.2
    var2    2   1
    var2    3   0.7
    var2    3   0.1
    var2    3   0.05
    var2    3   0.05
    var2    3   0.1 
    ;
run;

** count the number of obs per group **;
data test_ct; set test;
    by GROUP1 GROUP2;
    COUNT + 1;
    if first.GROUP2 then COUNT = 1;
run;

** count the total number of obs per group and output on each row **;
proc sql noprint;
    create table test_ct_all as
    select *, count(*) as COUNT_TOTAL
    from test_ct group by GROUP1,GROUP2
    order by GROUP1, GROUP2, COUNT;
quit;

** logic to keep records **;
data keep_flags; set test_ct_all;
    if COUNT=1 and COUNT_TOTAL=3 then KEEP=1;

    *the last record will have COUNT and COUNT_TOTAL equal;
    if COUNT_TOTAL > 3 and (COUNT_TOTAL ne COUNT) then KEEP=1;
run;

** output only the keep records **;
data keepers; set keep_flags;
    if KEEP=1;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  This looks perfect. I had worked my way through counting the number of observations per group but had gotten hung up after that.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem! Please upvote the answer if it works for you to let others know it has been answered as well!